# Why can not I create a Sharepoint project without a local URL?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a EventReceiver project in Sharepoint 2010 Templates, but VS always ask me to pass a valid local URL of a Sharepoint Site. Without a Sharepoint Site the project is not created. Why?

Why if I want to create the project and use it direct in production without local tests?

Answer (score 0):

This is a requirement of VS development for share point -- you need a local install of the sharepoint foundation server.  It is a free download.

But if you question is more along the lines of "Why make this a requirement", I don't know ;).  You can still have a sandbox server to deploy to.